# Custom ArrayAdapter rows don't show in the list

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom ArrayAdapter which contains a text and an image, but somehow the items don't show in the list. 
This is my custom adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DrawerArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] entries;
    private final Integer[] imageIds;

    public DrawerArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] entries, Integer[] imageIds) {
        super(context, R.layout.drawer_list_item, entries);

        this.context = context;
        this.entries = entries;
        this.imageIds = imageIds;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);
        TextView entryView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list_entry);
        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list_icon);
        entryView.setText(entries[position]);
        iconView.setImageResource(imageIds[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

And this is the Fragment:

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DrawerFragment extends ListFragment {

    private String[] drawerListEntries;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private Integer[] drawerListIcons;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerListIcons = new Integer[] {R.drawable.ic_action_user,R.drawable.ic_action_user,R.drawable.ic_action_user,R.drawable.ic_action_user};
        drawerListEntries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_items);
        setListAdapter(new DrawerArrayAdapter(getActivity(), drawerListEntries, drawerListIcons));


    }

    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_fragment, container, false);
     }

    @Override 
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    }


    @Override
     public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
        getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      //boolean drawerOpen = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_user).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

}
```

and this is my `drawer_list_item.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:padding="5dp" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="24sp" 
        android:textColor="@color/light_blue"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" >
      </TextView>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/drawer_icon">
    </ImageView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I should probably mention that when I just use  a normal ArrayAdapter with just text, it works perfectly. Anyone seeing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't want to inflate new views for every row in your custom adapter's getView() ignoring the provided convertView. ListViews don't use 1000 separate views when you have 1000 rows in the adapter, views get recycled.

So I would simply call:

```
View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

and then use view.findViewById() to set the data on your individual sub-views before returning the view that the ArrayAdapter returned. The ArrayAdapter already takes care of re-using recycled views.

Note that ArrayAdapter already sets the TextView itself, so you only need to set the ImageView, but for that the ArrayAdapter will need to know the id of your TextView, so use the constructor:

```
super(context, R.layout.drawer_list_item, R.id.drawer_list_entry, entries);
```

Because views are recycled make sure to always set the ImageView source. If a particular row has no image you need to clear it rather than do nothing.

EDIT: Another problem was related to the row layout. The vertical margin and padding was too much for the limited vertical row height of 70dp.

EDIT: Here an example of the adapter.

```
public class DrawerArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Integer[] mImageIds;

    public DrawerArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] entries, Integer[] imageIds) {
        super(context, R.layout.drawer_list_item, R.id.drawer_list_entry, entries);
        mImageIds = imageIds;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ((ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list_icon)).setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful tips. I just did what you mentioned, but neither the texts nor the images show up in the list? I get no errors/exception whatsoever. I can click the list items just fine and navigation also works, but no text or image. Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: In your drawer_list_item's LinearLayout use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. The vertical margin and padding is too much for the limited height of 70dp.

Comment: Thanks that kind of works. I see the icons now, but still no text and cannot figure out what's wrong. I also removed all paddings and margins from the text and still nothing to see. Do you see anything weird in TextView? I'm working on this for hours, this is so easy but irritating at the same time..

Comment: OK..I solved it now, but the problem was actually what you said in your answer. You said there is no need to set the TextView, but apparently I had to (even with super(context, R.layout.drawer_list_item, R.id.drawer_list_entry, entries);) put your comment about the ImageView in an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: The ArrayAdapter definitively sets the text and I can see it in your example without setting it manually. Updated answer with full adapter and the comment about the height.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions here.

1) Extend BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter.

2) implement getCount method of base adapter and return list.size as return value(integer). here list can be your arrays length.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, yes I can extend BaseAdapter and make ListRow class or something and put that in BaseAdapter, but do you also know the answer to my actual question?